# replacing the last four characters of the file in a directory

Tags: linux, unix

I have the below files in a dir in unix env at opt/app/tre

```
qweqtql.txt
drtqtol.txt
reqttgl.txt
seqwtpl.txt
```

now i want to remove the last four characters of the file name , and there can be n number of files in a directory 
but the command or unix script should scan all the files in a directory and replace the last four characters from the name itself.

so the outcome of the filenames would be

```
qwe.txt
drt.txt
req.txt
seq.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rename` command.

To remove the last four characters (`abcdefghijklmnopq.txt` to `abcdefghijklm.txt`):

```
rename 's/(.?+).{4}\.txt$/$1.txt/' *.txt
```

To remove everything except the first three characters (`abcdefghijklmnopq.txt` to `abc.txt`):

```
rename 's/(.{3}).*/$1.txt/' *.txt
```

---

If you want this operation to be performed for all `.txt` files within your folder (including subdirectories):

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec rename 's/(.?+).{4}\.txt$/$1.txt/' {}  \;
```

This correctly handles directories and filenames containing spaces, which can often be tricky to do right.

---

*PS:* Before you execute `rename` commands, it might be wise to first verify what it will do, using the `--no-act` option. In other words:

```
rename --no-act 's/(.?+).{4}\.txt$/$1.txt/' *.txt
```

Or:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec rename --no-act 's/(.?+).{4}\.txt$/$1.txt/' {}  \;
```

---

I assume you want this on files with the extension `.txt`. If not, let us know, and I'll modify it accordingly.

Comment: would fail on "abcdef.txtghi.txt"

Comment: @qdii Thanks. I've edited the answer to also handle that case

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily as:

```
for i in * 
do 
    mv $i `echo $i |  awk -F. '{print substr($1, 0, length($1)-3) "." $2}'`
done
```